Removing commits from github, solution: cloning branch from previous commit + removal of "old" branch?
I know that there were similar questions, but the answers that I've found does not answers fully my question. I am thinking about different solution than solutions suggested there.
I've published a code with "secret", by accident, on github.
I want to get rid of that commit. Solution that I am thinking about:

create another branch from previous commit
delete the old branch
rename the branch name to the current

Could anything go wrong? 1-2 people might downloaded the repository/have reference to it, but I might tell them to connect with "fresh" branch. I am now the only person that is working actively with that repository.

That won't be enough. Here is a guide on how to remove sensitive data from GitHub https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository. You will also need to contact them on their support portal to fully remove all sensitive data https://support.github.com/request/landing

If the repo is public, it's best to assume it has already been viewed and archived by bots, and perhaps some humans. If the secret is something that can be changed, then change it. (You can still also try to remove it...)
